# ConfigManagerErrorCode as string value (meaning)

Tags: c#, winapi

I was wondering whether there is a way to get the textual value of the error code(s) of the [Win32_PnPEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx) class? Are there any classes or (special) WMI queries (WQL)?

e.g. ConfigManagerErrorCode "0" = "**Device is working properly**."

Comment: Did a bit of Googling and found this: https://github.com/Miktor/pub/blob/master/Parsec.Configuration/WMIParser.cs  But it's not official Microsoft source.

Comment: Thx, I can use that code :) Please post your answer in a separate message, so I can accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not official Microsoft code, but it looks like a correct transcription. (Must admit that I found it via a bit of Googling, and haven't actually checked it for accuracy.)

https://github.com/Miktor/pub/blob/master/Parsec.Configuration/WMIParser.cs

Answer (score 0):

The official link for these codes is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity